# Log all errors in queries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

I have some applications in different programming languages. Some of them are legacy and I would not like to modify them.

Is there a way to log at server level all query errors, regardless of the application causing it?

I would like to know, for each error, the query causing it, the error type, and ideally loginame and hostname.

Comment: You can capture the XE event error_reported. Create a session for that event, specify a predicate (unless you want this for all databases) and have a file as the target for later consumption/analysis.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are just looking to log this information, you can set up an Extended Events session and capture the `error_reported` event.  Here is an example:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [ErrorCapture] 
ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.error_reported
(
    ACTION
    (
        sqlserver.client_hostname,
        sqlserver.database_id,
        sqlserver.sql_text,
        sqlserver.username
    )
    WHERE 
    (
        [severity] >= (11)
    )
) 
ADD TARGET package0.asynchronous_file_target
(
    SET filename=N'C:\SqlServer\Testing\ErrorCapture.xel'
)
WITH 
(
    MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,
    EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,
    MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,
    MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,
    MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,
    TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,
    STARTUP_STATE=ON
);
GO

ALTER EVENT SESSION [ErrorCapture]
ON SERVER
STATE = START;
GO
```

To test this out, here is a test error with `RAISERROR()`:

```
raiserror('This is a test error', 2, 1);
go
```

Then by looking at the XE log through the [sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280743.aspx) system function, you will be able to see all of the logged errors.

Comment: How do I delete an event session I don't need anymore?

Comment: `drop event session [EventSessionName] on server;` Where `[EventSessionName]` is the name of your event session that you want to drop.

Comment: [I am not sure if I am abusing your patience, I hope I am still within boundaries]
I get thousands of errors of type "Changed database context to 'MAINDB'" and "Changed language setting to us_english."
Is there a way to avoid logging these (non-)errors?

Comment: In other words, I would like to log errors with severity >= 11, while these are 10. Is it possible?

Comment: @carlo.borreo Absolutely.  You just need to specify a predicate for the event and have the severity set to 11 or higher.

Comment: @carlo.borreo I have modified my answer to include the predicate (`WHERE ([severity] >= (11) )`).  Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: @carlo.borreo No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Monitor for [Event Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189453.aspx) in the [Errors and Warnings Event Category](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177448.aspx). Specifically, the [Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187506.aspx) event will be raised for each error. For example, based on the code in [MS SQL Server third party transaction blocking monitor tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14834770/105929):

```
use msdb;
go

create queue [errors];
go

create service errors on queue [errors] (
    [http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostEventNotification]);
go

create event notification [errors]
    on server for EXCEPTION
    to service N'errors', N'current database';
go
```

If we check the queue, we'll see all exception reported:

```
receive cast(message_body as xml) from errors;


<EVENT_INSTANCE>
  <EventType>EXCEPTION</EventType>
  <PostTime>2013-02-19T13:52:21.443</PostTime>
  <TextData>Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__x__3213E83F31271CCE'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.x'. The duplicate key value is (1).</TextData>
  ...
  <HostName>...</HostName>
  <ApplicationName>Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query</ApplicationName>
  <LoginName>...</LoginName>
  ...
</EVENT_INSTANCE>
```